# How to identify a specific USB Port

Tags: java, linux, usb

I'm in a project that must perform "tests" on USB Pen Drives.
For that, I'm using a USB Hub (49 port Asic Miner - I'm using it due the number of ports).

I intend to plug 49 USB Pen drives on the HUB and test them using a Linux Java App. The test consists on "check if it is recognized", "storing and deleting data" and "check the size".

My problem is on the first step. If there is any Pen Drive that is not working properly, the system will recognize 48 pen drives, but I'll never know the specific device that is not working.

My question is: Is there any way to know the address (or something like that) of a specific usb port on a usb hub? For example: If I connect just one USB Pen Drive on port "34", my software will know that the device is connected on that specific port.

Thank you very much for your time and for your help!

Comment: were you able to ever figure out to do this?  I am doing something very similar with a Java app and struggling to identify ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) to execute the Linux command `mount`. It will list all devices currently mounted, manually or automatically, like:

```
/dev/sdb5 on /media/xdrive type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sdj1 on /media/Website type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,flush)
```

Here, second line describes the USB stick I have just plugged in (running Ubuntu). It can be easily recognized from the filesystem (vfat, and the hard drive above uses ext4) and it is mounted on /media/Website (because 'Website' is the stick label that has been used when formatting the stick in vfat). It should be trivial to parse the output and locate the mounted sticks (when formatting, I suggest to give the known labels matching the stick numbers).

If needed, you can put more information into the small file directly on the stick.

You can capture the output through the `Process.getOutputStream()`.

When done, you can safely unmount the sticks before pulling them out:

```
umount /media/Website
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check these libraries [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) and [usb2java](http://usb4java.org/) (they are a little out of date though).

However [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) will allow you to create an interface that interacts with different Operating Systems. This would allow you for cross-platform functionality. I'd look into [libUSB](http://www.libusb.org/) (because you are looking for Linux) for a good start!

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: To add to yours, USB4Java more recent activities (Mar 2014), and does seem to have cross platform support also (atleast their webpage says so). http://usb4java.org/